# Cant get random data in vue js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding

i want to get one of these names randomly in my html..
but i still cant get it to work :

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
 data: {
    items: [
      { name: 'You' },
      { name: 'Leonidas' }
     ]
 }, nowName : "",

 created () {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length);
    this.nowName = this.items[idx]
  }
})
```

this is my vue code, i dont know if it is okey and if i can get it back with {{ nowName }} . I tried it several times with method() and just function in data, but it doesnt give me a random back.

Comment: In components, data *must* be a function. What you've written above isn't a valid Vue component; if that's what you have in code, it won't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think that it isn't giving you a random item back? `idx` in your example will always return a whole number between `0` and `this.items.length`. (`0` or `1`). For example when running it 10 times:

```js
const items = [
  { name: 'You' },
  { name: 'Leonidas' }
];
new Array(10).fill(null).forEach((num) => {
  const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  console.log(items[idx]);
});
```

`nowName` isn't residing inside `data()` (which should be a function), is that maybe your issue?